# This is getting printed in my views: #<Recipe:0x10536ff28>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view, haml

Why am I seeing an activerecord object IDs  for each record coming out of my Recipe model in my recipes views?  At the bottom of the index action I see this:

```
#<Recipe:0x1056c1d98>#<Recipe:0x1056c1cd0>
```

The model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :quick_facts, :ingredients, :instructions, :user_id, :hashtag, :image
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

The view:

```
.section-header The Recipes as seen on: #DriscollsMoments
= recipes.each do |recipe|
  #recipe
    #image-container
      = link_to(image_tag(recipe.image_url, :width => 200, :height => 100, :border => 0), recipe_path(recipe.id))
    #information
      = link_to recipe.name, recipe_path(recipe.id), :class => 'recipe-name'
      = link_to 'view recipe & tweet', recipe_path(recipe.id), :class => 'view-recipe'
      .clear
      %p= recipe.description
  .clear
```

The Controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.find(:all)
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

This problem is unique to this model - it's not doing it anywhere else in my app.  I tried disabling carrierwave to see if that had any affect and it doesn't appear to make any difference.  I have two recipes_controllers, one's an admin controller, but that shouldn't be the problem either.  I know this is going to be obvious.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view, replace this:

```
= recipes.each do |recipe|
```

with this:

```
- recipes.each do |recipe|
```

The `=` causes the contents of the `recipes` array to be output after executing the loop.

Comment: Hahahahaha!  Thanks Dylan, I'm a bit embarrassed, but would have continued digging in WAAAAY too deep if I didn't post and you didn't reply so quickly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the line:

```
= recipes.each do |recipe|
```

should be:

```
- recipes.each do |recipe|
```